# Lowering the height of gnome application toolbars

Tags: gnome, i3, toolbar

I am using this gnome application called oregano in i3 window manager and it looks like all gnome applications do - they all have this large toolbar whose height is way too large.

[image]

Is there any way to decrease size of toolbar to a normal size for all gnome applications or maybe only for oregano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to decrease the size of toolbar by adding (or editing) the following line in your `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` file to make your icons small:

```
gtk-icon-sizes = panel-menu=16,16:gtk-large-toolbar=16,16
```

You will then notice the différence in GTK application like gedit.

You can also use this command to change the toolbar size of all gnome application:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/interface/toolbar_icons_size "small-toolbar"
```

and this command to restore the default large icons

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/interface/toolbar_icons_size "large-toolbar"
```